# Combine MySQL SELECT queries with IF statement

Tags: php, mysql, performance, join, select

I want to combine my two `SELECT` statements with an if statement. Currently I am just getting the row and then doing `if($row['activated'] === 1) { ... run 2nd select statement }`.

There has to be a better and much faster way of doing it (performance-wise). This is what I'm trying to do:

For example: (1st SELECT statement)

```
$db = $stmt->("SELECT * FROM users WHERE id = :id AND activated = 1");
$db->bindParam(':id', $id);
$db->execute();
```

**If** that above `SELECT` statement is true, then do this: (2nd SELECT statement)

```
$db = $stmt->("SELECT * FROM user_settings WHERE user_id = :user_id");
$db->bindParam(':user_id', $id);
$db->execute();
```

How can I combine those two SELECT statements? If it is `else` or if activated = 0, then only do the first select.

---

**Bonus question:**

How can I make it **three** If statements? For example, the 2nd SELECT statement will be like this:

```
$db = $stmt->("SELECT * FROM user_settings WHERE user_id = :user_id AND color = :color");
$db->bindParam(':user_id', $id);
$db->bindParam(':color', $color);
$db->execute();
```

Now **if** that statement is true, run this 3rd SELECT statement:

```
$db = $stmt->("SELECT * FROM friends WHERE user_id = :user_id");
$db->bindParam(':user_id', $id);
$db->execute();
```

Comment: "How can I combine those two SELECT statements? If it is else or if activated = 0, then only do the first select." Not sure that you mean there?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can merge/combine

```
SELECT * FROM user_settings WHERE user_id = :user_id AND color = :color
```

and

```
SELECT * FROM friends WHERE user_id = :user_id
```

Into one query with a JOIN

```
SELECT 
 *
FROM 
 user_settings
INNER JOIN 
 friends 
ON 
 user_settings.user_id = friends.user_id 
AND
 user_settings.color = :color
```

Or a other JOIN format

```
SELECT 
 *
FROM 
 user_settings
INNER JOIN 
 friends 
ON 
 user_settings.user_id = friends.user_id 
WHERE
 user_settings.color = :color
```

Or you can write it as this JOIN. (most likely slower)

```
SELECT 
 *
FROM (
  SELECT 
    *
  FROM 
   user_settings 
  WHERE
   user_settings.color = :color
) AS user_settings 
INNER JOIN 
 friends
ON
 user_settings.user_id = friends.user_id
```

The used method which is best/faster can/will be depending which indexes you have in use.

Comment: Thank you Raymond! I'm trying to see which is faster? The indexes used in each table are with the ID's but not color.

Comment: The first two are the same and will execute the same and uses the same indexes which ideally should be `user_settings(user_id, color_id)` and `friends(user_id)` @Capso28  the last query ideally should be the indexes `user_settings(color)`, `user_settings(user_id)` and `friends(user_id)`..

Comment: A single statement will be about twice as fast as two statements.  There is a lot of overhead.

Comment: "A single statement will be about twice as fast as two statements. There is a lot of overhead." @RickJames depening how many records are returned in the inner query and if a covering index can be used or not (in this case clearly not).. MySQL version also matters how it runs.. But i edited the question that the last query is most likely slower.

Comment: I used the last query approach more to optimize mainly `JOIN` queries which also use `ORDER BY` and `LIMIT` clauses See [this](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/eNTYPKwhB5ggcmbNZiGVPg/0) @RickJames i would choose the last query approach and execution plains over the other one in every MySQL version.. It is clear that MySQL 8.0 has the best optimizer because it correctly access the table `student` first to avoid the "fatal" combination "Using temporary; Using filesort" (slow performance when temporary table runs on disk instead off ram)  and reduces it to "using filesort" (quicksort algorithm) only